# Número de parámetros inválidos en foreach() usando PDO::FETCH_OBJ

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo el siguiente problema y por más que he mirado no encuentro donde está el error.

Tengo una clase llamada `Economy` que hereda de otra clase la conexión con la base de datos y con un método para leer los registros de un año en concreto.

La clase funciona bien porque tengo un método para añadir registros y funciona perfectamente, lo que no funciona es el siguiente procedimiento.

El método se llama `GetYearValues()` y dicho método recibe como parámetro un número para filtrar en la consulta. Este número es el año. En la base de datos este dato es de tipo `INTEGER` y el campo se llama `anyo`.

```
// Método para leer registros de un año en concreto
public function GetYearValues($year) {

    try {

        if(empty($year)) {

            echo "No se ha seleccionado ningún año.";

        } else {

            // Guardamos la sentencia sql
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM facturacion WHERE anyo = ?";

            // Creamos variable que hereda de conexión para preparar la consulta guardada en $sql
            $query = $this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);

            // Ligamos el parámetro de la consulta preparada
            $query->bindParam(1, $year, PDO::PARAM_INT);

            // Ejecutamos la consulta
            $query->execute(array());

            // Guardamos la consulta en una variable para usarla más tarde
            $resultado = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            // Cerramos la query
            $query->closeCursor();

            // Devolvemos los resultados de la conexión
            return $resultado;

            // Vaciamos el objeto de la conexión
            $this->conexion_db = null;

        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo "Error en la ejecución de la consulta<br>";
        echo "Mensaje " . $e->GetMessage() . "<br>";
        echo "Línea " . $e->getLine();

    }

}
```

Luego tengo la interfaz para elegir el año de la consulta, hay disponibles dos valores, 2016 y 2017:

```
<div class="container menu-index menu-search">
     <form action="consultareconomia.php" method="get">
         <label>Año: </label>
         <select id="year" name="year">
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
         </select>
         <br>
         <input type="submit" name="buscar" value="Buscar">
     </form>
 </div>
```

Y por último tengo la vista de los datos con el siguiente código, en la cabecera tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php

    // Incluimos la clase de Economia
    include __DIR__ . '/includes/economia.php';
    
    // Creamos un nuevo objeto
    $consultareconomia = new Economy();

    // Obtenemos los valores de los campos del formulario anterior: año
    if(isset($_GET["year"])){

      $year = $_GET["year"];

    }
   
    if(!empty($year)){

      // Si está cumplimentado el año buscará registros por ese valor
      $array_economia = $consultareconomia->GetYearValues($year);

    }
    
?>
```

Y la parte en el body donde genero la tabla con los registros:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr class="header-table">
      <td>Mes</td>
      <td>Año</td>
      <td>Importe Facturado</td>
      <td>Importe Invertido</td>
      <td>Impuestos</td>
    </tr>

    <?php

      foreach($array_economia as $elemento):

    ?>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo $elemento->mes ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $elemento->anyo ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $elemento->importefacturado ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $elemento->importeinvertido ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $elemento->importeimpuestos ?>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
      endforeach;
    ?>

</table>
```

El error que marca cuando pulso en `Buscar` es el siguiente:

> Mensaje SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Me da error en la línea 87 del `foreach`.

> `foreach($array_economia as $elemento):`

**¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?**

Comment: Creo que tu método `execute` no necesita como parámetro un array vacío, como le estás pasando ahora: `$query->execute(array());`, sino que debería ser: `$query->execute();`. Ver **[ejemplo número 4](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php)**  del Manual.

Comment: Gracias por responder @A.Cedano. Ayer me dió por probar y quité la consulta preparada, ahora en el SQL le paso lo que contenga el parámetro de la función (`$year`), sin usar `bindParam`. El resultado es que funciona. Por lo que creo que usando la consulta preparada no le está llegando ningún argumento a la función, de ahí el error `invalid parameter number`.

Comment: Aunque te funcione, no es la mejor opción, ya que tu código no es seguro. Las consultas preparadas evitarán la inyección SQL. En lugar de `bindParam` puedes usar `bindValue` y recuperar el conjunto de resultados en un array. **[Te dejo este ejemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/j4ye-3sgw)**, usando ese estilo debería funcionarte. Es importante tener un código seguro contra posibles ataques. Además las consultas preparadas aportan eficiencia a la hora de obtener los datos.

Comment: Si, yo también prefiero la consulta preparada. Lo pruebo tal y como me comentas y te cuento, pero como te dije, con la consulta preparada lo que está pasando es que el parámetro que está recibiendo la función no le llega a la sentencia SQL. Te comento en cuanto pueda modificarlo, muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @A.Cedano corregido el error, tenías razón, he cambiado `$query->execute(array())` por `$query->execute()`, de esta forma puedo usar la consulta preparada. Si quieres añades la respuesta para poder dártela como aceptada, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrego la respuesta para que la pregunta no aparezca como sin resolver.

El error está aquí:

> <s>$query->execute(array());</s>

pues **le estás pasando un array vacío en el `execute`**.

En PDO hay varias formas de pasar los parámetros, puedes usar cualquiera de ellas.

Para respetar el código como lo estás escribiendo, con esto bastaría:

```
       //...

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM facturacion WHERE anyo = ?";

        // Creamos variable que hereda de conexión para preparar la consulta guardada en $sql
        $query = $this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);

        // Ligamos el parámetro de la consulta preparada
        $query->bindParam(1, $year, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        // Ejecutamos la consulta
        $query->execute();

        // Guardamos la consulta en una variable para usarla más tarde
        $resultado = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        // Cerramos la query
        $query->closeCursor();

        // Vaciamos el objeto de la conexión
        // OJO: Esto debe ir antes del return
        $this->conexion_db = null;

        // Devolvemos los resultados de la conexión
        return $resultado;
```

**NÓTESE** que he trasladado el `return` al final de ese bloque. Cuando usas `return`, la función retorna a quien la ha llamado, por tanto, las líneas que siguen al `return` en el bloque no se ejecutan nunca.

---

El mensaje de error:

> Invalid parameter number: ....

ocurre porque además en PDO puedes [valerte de `execute` para pasar los parámetros](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php). De hecho, por eso te dice que el número de parámetros es inválido, porque reconoce el array vacío como parámetros y PDO esperaría en ese caso un array con un elemento, para sustituir al marcador `?` usado en la consulta.

Eso significa que también podrías escribir tu código así:

```
       //...

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM facturacion WHERE anyo = ?";

        // Creamos variable que hereda de conexión para preparar la consulta guardada en $sql
        $query = $this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);

        // Ejecutamos la consulta
        $query->execute(array($year));

        // Guardamos la consulta en una variable para usarla más tarde
        $resultado = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        // Cerramos la query
        $query->closeCursor();

        // Vaciamos el objeto de la conexión
        // OJO: Esto debe ir antes del return
        $this->conexion_db = null;

        // Devolvemos los resultados de la conexión
        return $resultado;
```

En este segundo caso, puesto que pasas los parámetros en el `execute`, **ya no necesitas usar `bindParam`**.

Answer (score -1):

Gracias a la ayuda de A. Cedano, sabemos que tu método `execute` no necesita como parámetro un array vacío, como le estás pasando ahora, lo que debes hacer es sustituir

```
$query->execute(array())
```

por

```
$query->execute()
```

Para que puedas mantener la protección contra inyección SQL y que tu consulta funcione correctamente, y de esta manera puedas evitar el error.

Comment: La respuesta en todo caso le correspondería a A. Cedano, no crees? De hecho le comenté que la incluyera para dársela por válida, dado que fue el quien dió con la solución.

Comment: @David Por supuesto que si, solo queria que se diera por finalizado este hilo, pero al parecer no le gusto a la comunidad. Con todo gusto la borro, no hay problema. (lo hice porque al parecer Cedano no esta interesado en publicar la respuesta)